# Does Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio store sql scripts which manipulate the tables in the databases managed by it?

Tags: sql-server

Does Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio store sql scripts which manipulate the tables in the databases managed by Management Studio, or do I have to manually manage the sql scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Can i expect SQL Server managemnt studio list those sql scripts for me to select some script from the list to run, so that I don't need to manually find the scripts to run?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually manage them. Two methods come to mind:

- Implement DDL triggers to capture every change:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/
- Use schema compare in visual studio to compare database and generate change scripts
- There' also this, which I've never used before: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1723/auto-generate-change-scripts-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-for-tables/